# Asset (image) public URL does not work

Tags: assets, url, routing

I wanted to include some uploaded assets (images) in an entry. The `.url` property in twig outputs the proper URL, in my case:

> http://localhost/craftcms/web/image/photo-2017-04-02-16-20-53-1.jpg

However, that link is broken. Following it leads to a 404 error page:

> Template not found: image/photo-2017-04-02-16-20-53-1.jpg

Viewing it in the admin panel preview also displays a broken image sign.

If I disable the Public URL switch in the asset settings, the image display fine in the admin panel, but obviously I cannot use them in public pages.

I wasn't able to find a working fix for this. I tried the multiple-environment config solution from these forums just in case, but it did not help me.

Update: here is a screenshot of my Assets volume settings:
[image]

Comment: What did you set the File System Path and the URL to? Is this a Craft 2 build?

Comment: The public URL needs to be publicly accessible, so in your web root folder. (the "web" folder by default in a craft3 project)

Is your assets folder in there?

Comment: This is a Craft 3 install. The public URL is indeed publicly accessible - inside the web folder as you suggested (see original post). The file system path - I also tried putting it in the web folder, as well as outside of it. No avail

Comment: Can you please update your question with a screenshot of the Asset volume settings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that your Asset Volume URL is `@web/image` but your Asset Volume path is `@webroot/assets/art`

That means that Craft will look for the images on disk (to do transforms, etc.) in `web/assets/art` but it will generate URLs for frontend requests that point to `http://example.com/image` -- where presumably nothing exists.

These should probably be:

- URL: `@web/assets/art`
- Path: `@webroot/assets/art`

...assuming that the `web/assets/art/` directory is where these images live.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. Question: what if I want to have my images stored outside webroot, but have public URLs? How can I achieve that? Thank you

Comment: It can be done, but why would you want to do that?

Comment: I want to find out what the system is capable of and what its limitations are

Comment: @andrew.welch, can you elaborate on the configuration required for storing the assets on disk outside of the web root?

My use case for doing this is in a development environment where I'd like the base asset path to be an environment variable storing a path to a shared disk location where assets are maintained for all developers that are developing the site.

I can serve the assets from another base path using some Nginx configurations, but I'm interested to know if it's possible without this.